# Error and residue in linear system

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the linear system $A x = b$ with a computed solution, what will be the relation between error and residue?

Comment: How do you define error and residue?

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you saw what you understand by error and residue.

In most literature, the residual corresponds to the vector of differences like:  $\mathbf{r} = A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}$. The error (usually an scalar quantity) corresponds to the norm of the residual: $e = ||A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b} ||$.